# Error when trying to run the application on ESP32

Tags: toit

I'm back to toit for the first time since February and I'm having a strange problem when I try to run the app:

```
micrcx@micrcx-desktop:~/toit_apps$ toit -d=dell run bubble_sort.toit
2022-06-22T20:21:52.332+0300    WARN    Compiler.toitc  compiler/compiler.go:299        /home/micrcx/.cache/toit/sdk/v1.6.20/toitc: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/micrcx/.cache/toit/sdk/v1.6.20/toitc)
/home/micrcx/.cache/toit/sdk/v1.6.20/toitc: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/micrcx/.cache/toit/sdk/v1.6.20/toitc)

File not found: '/home/micrcx/toit_apps/bubble_sort.toit'
```

But the file exists:

```
micrcx@micrcx-desktop:~/toit_apps$ ls -al bubble_sort.toit
-rw-r--r-- 1 micrcx micrcx 326 Mar 10  2021 bubble_sort.toit
micrcx@micrcx-desktop:~/toit_apps$
```

Answer (score 1):

The `toit` executables were built on a machine with a recent glibc.

There are two options to fix this issue:

1. upgrade your Linux
2. the Toit team builds the `toit` executables without dependencies to a recent glibc.

Thanks to your report, 2. is much simpler, as a new version without the glibc dependency is being worked on.

Comment: Thanks for reaction & answer. Well, I'll wait until there is toit executables without the glibc dependency. I hope this happens in the very near future.